# Semaphores not working on threads

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand how `semaphores` work in `C++` but I am having some troubles.

Here is my code:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <pthread.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
  #include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
  #include <semaphore.h>

  using namespace std;

  static sem_t *sem_thread;
  static pthread_t thread_id;

  void * threadFunc(void *) {
     cout << "threadFunc\n";
     cout << "threadFunc\n";
     cout << "threadFunc\n";
     cout << "threadFunc\n";
     cout << "threadFunc\n";

     sem_post(sem_thread);

     return 0;
  }

  int main()
  {
     // Init semaphores
     sem_thread = sem_open("./semaphores/sem_thread", O_TRUNC, 0777, 0);

     // Init thread
     int rc = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, threadFunc, NULL);
     if (rc != 0)
     {
        cerr << "Pthread couldn't be created. rc=" << rc << endl;
        abort();
     }
     sem_wait(sem_thread);

     cout << "Main thread\n";
     cout << "Main thread\n";
     cout << "Main thread\n";
     cout << "Main thread\n";
     cout << "Main thread\n";

     sem_close(sem_thread);
     sem_unlink("./semaphores/sem_thread");

     return 0;
  }
```

So I expect the program to print `threadFunc` first and then `Main thread`. However, this is what I get:

```
Main thread
tMhariena dtFhurneca
dt
hMraeiand Ftuhnrce
atdh
rMeaaidnF utnhcr
etahdr
eMaadiFnu ntch
rteharde
adFunc
```

Any idea of what's happening?

Comment: Documentation does not say anything about O_TRUNC flag for `sem_open`, why do you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not creating the semaphore, nor checking whether it was created.

There are two problems with your call to [`sem_open`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open):

- you need `O_CREAT`, not `O_TRUNC`, to create it.
- the name isn't valid. Named semaphores aren't kept in the filesystem.

Looking at [`man sem_overview`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview), the naming convention is specified thusly:

> A named semaphore is identified by a name of the form /somename;
>     that  is,  a  null-terminated  string of up to NAME_MAX-4 (i.e.,
>     251) characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by  one
>     or  more  characters,  none of which are slashes.